# Use two different keyboards with different layouts in FreeBSD in X environment

Tags: xorg, freebsd, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have bought a laptop and installed FreeBSD on it. I am now trying to finish this all.

The laptop has a Danish keyboard, but I have also a USB typematrix keyboard with bépo (French Dvorak) layout and would like to be able to use them both, at least in a graphical environment.

I think that's it. To make it clear, I want each keyboard to be usable in X with its own keymap like normal and not having to switch with a key each time I actually switch keyboard.

I have read about kbdmux.

Can I tell `kbdmux` to use bépo keymap when receiving input from the USB keyboard, while relying on the Danish keymap while on the board keyboard? The console keymap is the danish.iso keymap, as set in `/etc/rc.conf`.

Or should I disable `kbdmux` and address the keyboards and their maps in `xorg.conf`?

Answer (score 0):

Kbdmux combines two keyboard to one by switching the original devices to only return scancodes and translating them through only one keymap. When using Xorg kbdmux itself is switched to just return scancodes with Xorg doing the translation. The problem is of course that Xorg only sees one keyboard attached. So, I think your idea is in fact the only possible solution. You have to disable kbdmux and connect the real keyboards as individual instances to Xorg.